# Getting layers to html with mouseover for all layers?

Tags: qgis

I'm a casual user of Qgis for my job.  This latest project has taken me to unfamiliar waters and I need advice on last remaining steps to get me to my goal.  My goal is to have a choropleth map of the lower 48 states of America with another layer of cities. Using data from the attribute tables imported by csv, I want the mouse over (tool tip) feature to work for both layers simultaneously rather than just the one selected.  Then I want to image map this to html so I can use it in web form.

I've gotten all the way to creating html tool tips in the layer properties screen but this is where I'm stuck.

How do I get the tool tips to work on two layers simultaneously in an html format for web use?

With new projection suggested by user3338197.

[image: With new projection thanks to user3338197]